# iTextSharp Use Link Inside PdfPCell

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, anchor, itext, cell

I am able to successfully put a link in the pdf with a friendly name:

```
            Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Google", linkFont);
            anchor.Reference = "https://www.google.com";
            doc.Add(anchor);
```

[image]

However, I cannot get get the anchor to work within a PdfPCell.
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
            var memberCell = new PdfPCell();
            Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Google", linkFont);
            anchor.Reference = "https://www.google.com";
            memberCell.AddElement(new Anchor(anchor));
```

That displays the exception: **System.ArgumentException: Element not allowed.**

I also tried:

```
            var memberCell = new PdfPCell();
            Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Google", linkFont);
            anchor.Reference = "https://www.google.com";
            memberCell.AddElement(new Phrase(anchor));
```

This does not throw an exception but it isn't a link it is just the word "Google".

I am using the newest version of iTextSharp at this time v.(5.4.4.0)
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of an `Anchor` use a `Chunk` and call the `SetAnchor()` method:

```
var c = new Chunk("Google");
c.SetAnchor("https://www.google.com");
memberCell.AddElement(c);
```

Comment: How do I get the anchor in the chunk to open a new tab in the browser when clicked?